# Hide output from cronjobs running in background

Tags: linux, cron

I have few python cronjobs running at a regular interval, set up in crontab. Now I have `crond -b` running in the background. However, I get following message printed on the console for every run of the cronjob

`crond[27827]: USER root pid 27829 cmd python mypythonscript.py`

How can I hide these outputs from appearing in the console?

Comment: do you have `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirect command at the end of your cronjob?

Comment: yes, all cronjobs end with `>/dev/null 2>&1` in crontab.
Also, if I run `crond -b >/dev/null 2>&1` it does not change the behavior

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is `crond` writing the `syslogs` and nothing to do with redirecting logs to `/dev/null`. You could try editing `/etc/sysconfig/crond` file to set `CRONDARGS` to

```
CRONDARGS="-s off"
```